# Obtaining the runtime type of a derived template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, rtti

I can use say `typeid` or `dynamic_cast` to switch between derived base class instances. For example:

```
struct B { virtual ~B() {} };

struct D1 : B {};
struct D2 : B {};

void doit(B &b) {
  if      (dynamic_cast<D1 *>(&b)) foo1();
  else if (dynamic_cast<D2 *>(&b)) foo2();
}
```

How can I continue in this vein when the derived type is a template instantiation? For example, how could I extend the `doit` function above to handle four cases; perhaps using the `DT1` and `DT2` classes below, instantiated with arbitrary types?

```
template <typename T>
struct DT1 : B {};

template <typename T>
struct DT2 : B {};
```

Comment: *"How can I continue in this vein"* - By making `doit` a function template. What you are really asking is a mixture of paradigms (compile template types vs. runtime dynamic types). That's not going to pan out well.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to describe your overall goal, as somebody may have a different way to approach this that will work a lot better.  Also, you may consider looking into [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding the list of derived classes in the `doit` function you could maintain some sort of registry of `foo` functions to call for each type. In the simplest form this could just be a `vector` of `std::function<void(B&)>` and you just loop through and call each of them. Each `std::function` would be responsible for checking if the type matches:

```
auto& doitRegistry(){
  static std::vector<std::function<void(B&)>> registry;
  return registry;
}

void doit(B &b) {
  for (auto& f : doitRegistry()) {
    f(b);
  }
}
```

If you wanted to be smarter the registry could be something like a `std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void(B&)>>` so that you don't have to loop through the whole registry but as long as you don't have a huge number of derived classes it probably doesn't matter much.

Then you just have to register each type of derived class in the registry. You can create a helper class that registers a function in the registry in its constructor:

```
struct DoItRegistration {
  DoItRegistration(std::function<void(B&)> foo) {
     doitRegistry().push_back(std::move(foo));
  }
};
```

And create a static instance of this class per derived class:

```
template <typename T>
struct DT1 : B {
  DT1() {
        registerWithDoIt();
  }
  static DoItRegistration& registerWithDoIt() {
      static DoItRegistration registration([](B &b){
        if (dynamic_cast<DT1<T>*>(&b)){
         foo1();
        }
      }); 
      return registration;
  }
};
```

So that on first use of a derived class it registers itself with the `doit` registry and will be called when needed:

```
int main() {
    DT1<double> d1;
    DT1<int> d2;
    DT2<double> d3;
    DT1<double> dupeType;

    doit(d3);  // calls foo2()
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ybd4lMIRp7vzIuZR).

Comment: Now that's thinking outside the box. Thanks. I'm really hoping though for a solution that only modifies the `doit` function. It may be impossible.